# $A_5$ is generated by all 3 cycles

Tags: symmetric-groups

There are some similiar questions, but it seems that there is some different equal definition to $A_5$.
The definition I'm using for $A_5$ is that this is the kernel of the sign homomorphism- i.e all the permutations with even number of transpositions. 
I would like to get help with the equivalence of this definition , to the definition of subgroup of $S_5$ , generated by all cycles of order 3.

**EDIT- THERE IS AN ANSWER ON THE LINK IN COMMENTS**

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868836/every-alternating-permutation-is-a-product-of-3-cycles

Comment: Thank you- that will do the trick :)

Answer (score -2):

A5 is the group [3,3,3]+ or [3,5]+ in Coxeter notation.

You could make it, I suppose, out of (AB)³ = (BC)³ = (CD)³ = I, and (AC)² = (BD)² = (DA)² = I, which is what the first symbol means.

The second one means (AB)³ = (BC)^5 = (AC)² = I, which is what the second definition.

A5 is a relatively primitive group, but you can indeed generate A5 from purely cycles of three.

Comment: Can you please descrive the idea in the usual notation of symetrices?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "usual notation of symmetries".  I dabble in higher dimension stuff, not maths.  So these are copies from Conway and Coxeter.  It's a matter of walking the Cayley diagrams, the omnitrunc pentachoron, and the rhombotruncated icosadodecahedron resp.